# How do I export a default value (text based) from RedCap?

Tags: export, default-value, redcap

I have a few forms in RedCap. Per some reporting requirements my work has, I'd like to include on those forms some default text values that differ per form. So for example, for Form A, I'd like to have a variable that exports with the data that defaults to "Apples" for every entry. And for Form B, I'd like to have a variable that exports with the data that defaults to "Blueberries" for every entry. It feels like a straightforward ask, but I'm struggling with making it happen (have very recently switched from Microsoft Access to RedCap for data tracking).

Of note - not sure whether it's important or not - the variable doesn't need to be shown on the outward facing form. It's just a variable important for the export process (to make things as automated as possible).

I've tried to use the @DEFAULT and @SETVALUE Action Tags, but neither of those seem to support exporting. I couldn't get @DEFAULT to even default to text and show it in the form. @SETVALUE worked within the form, but then didn't export. As per my note, I would like to combine whatever solution I use with the @HIDDEN action tag.

Comment: SETVALUE and DEFAULT are executed when you open those forms, so if you add them in, you'd have to open every record and save those forms. Look into @CALCTEXT as a way to generate that text value, and then run Data Quality Rule H to backfill all records, then export.